# MySQL Event Scheduler syntax for insert and delete

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, scheduler

I was wondering if you can tell me what's wrong with the ff sql statement:

```
insert into translog 
  select * from transponder_logs where trans_log_id < 150000;
delete from transponder_logs where trans_log_id < 150000
```

This statement ran just fine in sql but it gives me a syntax error when I used it on `event scheduler`.

The error message was:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use  near `'delete from transponder_logs where trans_log_id < 150000` at line 3"

Comment: Error message say line 6, so is that the whole statement? Also, _how_ are you submitting this to the database?

Comment: My bad. Blank rows were counted. I've edited my original post. Line 3 is where the delete statement starts. Yes it is the whole statement. Im submitting the statement using the scheduled events window of mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you define code like routines that have multiple executable statements, you *MUST* define a custom `DELIMITER`. And your code will be sent to the server along with delimiter instruction. And the server compiles the code as a *block* before it finds the newly defined custom delimiter.

Read what documentation says:
[`Defining Stored Programs`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the `delimiter` command. .... The delimiter is changed to // to enable the entire definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ; delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.

I believe your event scheduler code is just executed as is without defining such `delimiter`.

Change it as following:

```
-- set the new delimiter
DELIMITER //

-- include your event scheduler code block here

-- lastly terminate the code block, with new delimiter
-- so that server starts compiling the code

//

-- now reset the delimiter to default
DELIMITER ;
```

**Refer to**: [*CREATE EVENT Syntax*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)

Comment: DELIMITER // insert into translog select * from transponder_logs where trans_log_id < 150000; delete from transponder_logs where trans_log_id < 150000 end // DELIMITER ;

Comment: I tried this so it now looks something like this: DELIMITER // insert into translog select * from transponder_logs where trans_log_id < 150000; delete from transponder_logs where trans_log_id < 150000 end // DELIMITER ;       I still get an error and this time it says to check for the right syntax to use near // at line 1

Comment: It seems you have not included `BEGIN`. And also, I am not sure how your `create event ...` code looks like. Unless you post it in your question area, it is hard to guess and advise you.

Comment: Refer to documentation on [*Create Event Syntax*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html). It has enough of examples one of which resembles your specific requirement (insert and delete).

Comment: You are right. Its working now. So the problem all along was the "begin" and "end" keyword. So when I added both even without the delimiter it was accepted. "BEGIN insert into translog 
 select * from transponder_logs where trans_log_id < 150000;
delete from transponder_logs where trans_log_id < 150000 END" Thank you Ravinder for your help.